# How to filter result based on birthdate and min/max age values in Parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse iOS SDK. I want to filter users based on their specified age ranges.

I have two tables:

1st, **tableUser** which has a field titled `birthdate` with a `String` data type.

2nd, **tableSettings** which has two fields `minAge` and `maxAge`, both of which are `Number` types

I want to fetch users from the `tableUser` class who's age, calculated from birthdate field, falls between the age range specified in the `tableSettings` class. For example, if the `minAge` value is 20 and the `maxAge` value is 25, then I only want to retrieve users with an age between this range.

Is this possible? How would I make such a query?

Comment: I hope you have relation between these two

Comment: No, I don't have that.. but I do have a common field in both. That's userID.

Comment: ok cool let me see if I can give the rough idea

Comment: Seems like very complex thing, first you have to calculate the age (in 1st table) the check the range (in second table) and based on that fetch the users from the fist table. I hope it can be possible. You can learn from here https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS see if anything here works for you

Comment: For the "birthdate" field in the tableUser class, is the string just an age value like "21"? Or is it an actual date?

Comment: Its a date in string format, for e.g. 06-09-1988 (dd-mm-yyyy) format. @Aaron

Comment: How and why did you create this data structure if you had this requirement in mind ? You'll probably need to use cloud code to get any kind of fast response and I expect you'll need to make multiple queries.

Comment: @Wain, I'd not create it, it was come to us as incomplete project. Half of the app was already developed then we've to integrate this kind of logics. Yes, you're right. Cloud code may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement sounds non-trivial with that suboptimal data structure. I'd probably go for cloud code to hide the required logic from the app. This logic would be to query the `tableSettings` and calculate the date range that applies.

Now that you have this range, it's still hard to use because your other table uses a string representation of the date rather than a true `Date` type. This really sucks. If you can you should change the date to the correct type, or at least add another column with a correct representation of the date (but then you have to keep them in sync).

Working with dates you can add specific range criteria to your query and life is easy.

Working with strings is compounded in difficulty because you have the day first, so you can't even use `BEGINSWITH` to filter the query on year and then process the content. It really is a terrible data model for the problem. So this basically leaves you paging through everything doing an explicit conversion of the string to a date and then comparing that to the range.

If you at all can, change the data model. Even if you create a new class (table) specifically for this data and use an `afterSave` hook to keep them in sync.

Comment: Thanks Wain ! I'm aware of this but unfortunately there's something that's not in my hand. I would probably going to patch this case.